Matcad FFT plot using ALLEEG in EEGLAB
I tried following the codes for plotting Matcad FFT using the ALLEGG in EEGLab here
https://devcodef1.com/news/1232023/matlab-fft-plot-alleeg

ALLEEG = pop_loadset('ALLEEG.set');
chans = find(strcmp(ALLEEG.chanlocs(:,3),'1'));
[~,~,~,~,~,~,~,~,spec] = spectopo(ALLEEG,chans,1,256,1);
plot(spec.freq,spec.powrel);
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Power');


But the codes returned errors:

Why did it create the error:
"Error using spectopo
Too many output arguments."
I've tried different combinations including using the sample dataset at EEGlab but it still produces that error. How to fix it?

Have you checked ALLEEG has it the format as you expect it? Additionally you should check the function spectopo, how many output variables are there? Nevertheless, the answer to your questions is, go through your script step by step, check each result, familiarize yourself with the functions you are using, in other words debug it (how-to-debug-small-programs)
